# How to create Curved & Overlapping Menu Tabs in CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, border, css-shapes

I want to make a menu, in which the ends of the menus overlap and they have curved borders and slightly slanting edges.

Without using a background image, is it possible to do such a menu with only CSS?

For better understanding, have attached the sample of menu below. Want to know how to make the parts marked in red using CSS alone.

[image]

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: not exactly what you need but... http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing. I googled it out to find that. But, I want slanting edges as well.. So how to do it?

Comment: ya... good question! Have you tried already anything? Or you're just wondering if it's possible in pure CSS?

Comment: Even more: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/.

Comment: RokoC.Buljan: Haven't tried anything yet. But was just wondering if it is possible only in CSS. All these days I just used to use background images, which is not a good idea as the menus have to be responsive too. Am building it on Bootstrap. So, thought will do it with only CSS if possible.

DOCASAREL: Thanks for pointing. The trapeziod looks close. But, I want overlapping edges (I know how to make round edges though).

Comment: I just observed now.. the menus style on the website css-tricks.com is exactly what I wanted.. How to see the menu source code? :)

Comment: @PrashanthJC hit F12 :) target the element with the Element Selector and observe the Styles tab

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah.. trying to figure it all out :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image: Curved UL LI list tabs]

- Skew the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements,
- set pseudos to some `-` offset
- add left-top `border-radius` to `:before` and right-top to `:after`
- if needed (to remove the top hard edge) add top border radius to the A element
- add `z-index:1;` to the `:after`
- add `z-index:1;` to the *.active*'s `:before` element.

```css
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8BBF50;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #8BBF50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 22px;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 2, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0; /* just to smooth the top edges */
}

nav a:before,
nav a:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 23px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
}

nav a:before {
  border-radius: 12px 0 0 0;
  transform: skew(-24deg);
  left: -13px; /* play with this one to give the LI border ~2px extrusion */
}

nav a:after {
  border-radius: 0 12px 0 0;
  transform: skew(24deg);
  right: -13px; /* play with this one to give the LI border ~2px extrusion */
  border-right: 1px solid #628E2F;
  z-index: 1; /* overlap next element */
}


/* LI ACTIVE  */

nav li.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

nav li.active a {
  color: #8BBF50;
  background: #fff;
}

nav li.active a:before {
  z-index: 1; /* overlap prev element */
}

nav li.active a:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Products</a></li>
    <li><a>Map</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The above does not provide the concave curvature at the bottom of the tab, instead I used the LI element border-bottom 2px extrusion to give a slight feeling to the eye. Not perfect but still a nice solution.

[image: Curved list tabs - detail]

[live demo on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/rebini/3/edit)

Comment: Thanks for this contribution! I took it and modified the aesthetics only a touch. It works wonderfully. I managed to use it as a base upon which to import a SharePoint list to generate the tabs with tooltips. A separate list will fill the sundry of DIVs underneath that these tabs will call. I thickened the border on the right to look like a shadow and added a 1px border on the left. With the top border 0, this makes the tabs pop!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan and others: [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/+EricHein/albums/6067069230134559473/6067069237813617874?sqi=103644918931411982462&sqsi=6a2abc8f-3041-4e70-a8b5-e5bfcc4134ab&pid=6067069237813617874&oid=109998058047277899632) is a dynamically loaded example. I implemented the panes below as selectively revealed <div>s with jquery.

Comment: I'll need to look at Sublime then. I hear much about it, but being on a managed system, my options are limited to installed apps and what I can fool into running in user space. *just downloaded the portable version!*

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved It.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wL080v6c/)

Here is What I've added to The Code given at: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

I've Just added, `background-color` property to pseudo element `:before` and `:after` of `.active` `li`'s css.

As follows:

```
.tabs li { 
  /* Makes a horizontal row */
  float: left; 

  /* So the psueudo elements can be
     abs. positioned inside */
  position: relative; 
  /*Make Sure The Li's stays Inline */
   display:inline-block;
  /* Remove Ugly Chromes `.` */
   list-styling:none;
}
.tabs .active a { 
  /* Colors when tab is active */
  background: #aea; /* Added Green Color */ 
  color: black; 
}
.tabs li:last-child:after,   .tabs li:last-child a:after,
.tabs li:first-child:before, .tabs li:first-child a:before,
.tabs .active:after,   .tabs .active:before, 
.tabs .active a:after, .tabs .active a:before {
    content: "";
    background: #afa; 
  }
.tabs .active:before, .tabs .active:after {
  background: white; 
  background:#afa;  
  /* Squares below circles */
  z-index: 1;
}
.tabs .active a:after, .tabs .active a:before {
  background: #ddc385;
}
```

and here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL080v6c/1/) after adding some `JQuery` to make it live. 
Hope it helps :).

Comment: not at all what OP is looking for :) Or your fiddle is messed up.

Comment: Also the OP's interest was not how to remove the first and last element shape :)

Comment: I see a new style menu altogether. Anyways, thanks for your time :)