# Rectangle with strange rounded bottom side

Tags: css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

I've been reading about how to make a rectangle with the bottom side rounded. I found that I can make a rectangle rounded side, not rounded corners.

```css
.figure {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>
```

But I can't make it look like this image.

[image]

I really appreciate If you guys could help me. Thanks!

Comment: `100%30px` – that is not a valid CSS length value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SVG**:

The shape was rebuilt on *Adobe Illustrator* (free alternative: *Inkscape*) and got improved since it wasn't symmetrical as you see in the following picture comparing the original image behind with the pink line:

[image: pink line]

SVG produces more code lines but allows you to build unique and detailed shapes (it's worth in this case since it's a big element with a great importance on the page layout).

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  max-width: 100%;
}

path {
  fill: #4f3b6a; 
}

span {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 16%;
}
```

```html
<div id=header>

<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 180">
<path d="M0,0c0,0,0.085,57.702,0.085,77.429c42.108,3.792,84.187,7.988,126.333,11.294c100.844,7.912,201.861,12.082,302.976,14.923
 c132.122,3.715,258.477,4.525,390.619,2.69c3.054-0.043,4.721,1.115,6.438,3.565c10.835,15.457,22.122,30.6,32.771,46.182
 c11.62,17,26.813,23.914,47.781,23.914c2.441,0,102.813,0,105.994,0c20.968,0,36.161-6.914,47.781-23.914
 c10.647-15.582,21.937-30.725,32.771-46.182c1.719-2.451,3.386-3.609,6.438-3.566c132.145,1.835,258.497,1.021,390.618-2.689
 c101.113-2.842,202.133-7.013,302.977-14.923c42.146-3.307,84.225-7.503,126.333-11.294C1919.915,57.702,1920,0,1920,0H0z"/>
</svg>
  
<span>DESTINOS</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{margin:0; font:16px/1 sans-serif;}
.figure{
  position:      relative;
  background:    #4C3966;
  height:        40px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
}
.figure a{
  color:      #fff;
  background: inherit;
  position:   absolute;
  bottom:     0;
  left:       50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, 95%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 95%);
  padding:    8px 11px;
  border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}
.figure a:before,
.figure a:after{
  content:  " ";
  position: absolute;
  top:      0;
  width:    23px;
  height:   100%;
  background-color: inherit; 
}
.figure a:before{
  border-radius: 0 0 0 12px;
  transform:     skew(24deg);
  left:          -13px;
}
.figure a:after{
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 0 ;
  transform:     skew(-24deg);
  right:         -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <a>DESTINOS</a>
</div>
```

mainly from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25713496/383904

Answer (score 2):

give this a shot: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/c6jxzL2m/2/

```
<div class="figure"></div>

.figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}
.figure:before {
  background-color: purple;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%30px; 
}
.figure:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border-top: 31px solid purple;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%30px; 
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general current thinking is NOT to use CSS for this, but rather use SVG.

However, it is possible to round sides but the effect may not be precisely what you are looking for.

```css
.figure {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px / 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I've tried. It's not perfect but it's almost look-a-like I think.

> CSS

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; }
.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: purple; 
  position: relative; 
}

.full:before { content: ""; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 50%; margin-left: -150px; background: purple; bottom: -30px; height: 50px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50%30px; border-bottom-right-radius:50%30px;   transform: rotate(2deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }
.full:after { content: ""; position: absolute; right: 0; left: 50%; margin-right: -150px; background: purple; bottom: -30px; height: 50px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50%30px; border-bottom-right-radius:50%30px;   transform: rotate(-2deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); }

.figure {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto; 
    background-color: purple;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 250%30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 250%30px;
    position : relative; 
    transform: rotate(1deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    margin-top:27px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
    color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: arial; z-index: 10;
}

.figure:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px; bottom: 0; top: -95px;
  content: "";
  width:65px;border-bottom-left-radius: 100%10px; border-bottom-right-radius:100%10px; z-index: -1
}

.figure:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px; bottom: 0; top: -105px;
  content: "";
  width:70px;border-bottom-left-radius: 100%10px; border-bottom-right-radius:100%10px;  z-index: -1
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ckug4ahx/9/)

Answer (score 0):

For the fun, because `mix-blend-mode` is not avalaible everywhere:

```css
div {
  background: #4F3D6D;
  border: solid;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100% /2em;
}
div h1 {
  border: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 99.5%;
  background: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  /* shrinks on content */
  border-radius: 0 0 180px 180px /0 0 200px 200px;
}
div h1:before,
div h1:after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: -3px -2.1em -0.25em;
  background: inherit;
  border-left: solid;
  transform: skew(22deg)
}
div h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  transform: skew(-22deg);
  margin: 0 0 0 -1.06em;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: solid;
}
html {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/800/abstract/1) top center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Destiny</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

</div>
```

[Pen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JXMJWP?editors=1100)